# JQuery mobile vclick wont fire

Tags: jquery-mobile

Im'trying here to bind vclick event on div in which is my gmap, so than on click (or touch) it changes page to my map page. But when i add to code

```
$map.vclick(function(){
$.mobile.changePage($('#map_directions'));
)};
```

gmap won't show and div is not clickable (i've tried with

```
 $map.bind('vclick', function(e) {
    $(event.target).trigger('touchstart');
    $.mobile.changePage($('#map_directions'));
});
```

also

here's my code:

```
$(document).delegate('#info','pagecreate',function(){
var SelectedOptionClass = $('option:selected').attr('class');
$('div.ui-select').addClass(SelectedOptionClass);
$('#note_utilisateur').live('change', function(){
$('div.ui-select').removeClass(SelectedOptionClass);
SelectedOptionClass = $('option:selected').attr('class');
$('div.ui-select').addClass(SelectedOptionClass);
});
var $map = $("#info div:jqmData(role=place_map)");

$map.vclick(function(){
$.mobile.changePage($('#map_directions'));
)};

$map.gMap({
mapTypeControl:         false,
zoomControl:            false,
panControl:             false,
scaleControl:           false,
streetViewControl:      false,
latitude:43.320204,
longitude:21.892635,
zoom: 15,
onComplete: function() {
            $map.gMap('addMarker', {
            latitude:43.320204,
            longitude:21.892635,
            title:'Gnezdo',
            });
        }
});
```

});

and html:

```
 <div class="ui-block-b" id = "place_map" data-role ="place_map" style="width:150px";>
            Loading map..
 <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the .on()-method like in the following example:

```
  $( document ).on( "vclick", "#map", function() {
      ... do sth ...
    });
```

Comment: if you copied the method 1:1 it won't work, adapt it to your code.

Comment: ofc i've adapted it, I tried it several ways but i just won't make div clickable.